# R: Updating based on previous entry in data frame

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have a dataframe `diff` in R that looks like this:

```
> head(diff)
        svd next_svd      delta Component Selected?
1 286178.77 54993.91 4.20382638                TRUE
2  54993.91 25194.36 1.18278651                TRUE
3  25194.36 19643.22 0.28259842               FALSE
4  19643.22 15580.04 0.26079366               FALSE
5  15580.04 14549.86 0.07080343               FALSE
6  14549.86 11496.45 0.26559570               FALSE
```

I would like to check the values of `Component Selected?` and update the value based on this check. Essentially if the entry in the row above is `FALSE` I would like to assert that the current entry be changed to `FALSE`.

I have achieved the desired effect with the following code:

```
  for(row in 2:nrow(diff)){
    if(!diff$`Component Selected?`[row-1]){
      diff$`Component Selected?`[row]<- FALSE
    }
  }
```

In the interest of speeding up my code and avoiding `for` loops in R, as I once was advised, I was wondering if anyone has solutions to achieve this without a `for` loop that would increase the speed.

Thanks!

Comment: if speed is only concern you can try `for each` loop for parallelization: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreach/vignettes/foreach.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In R base, you can do:

```
df$Component_Selected[setdiff(which(!df$Component_Selected), nrow(df)) + 1] <- FALSE
```

So, basically,

1. you get the indices for which your column is `FALSE`,
2. you remove the index of the last row if present,
3. you add one to all these indices,
4. finally you assign values to `FALSE` for these new indices.

Comment: I checked this solution before accepting it, thank you, it works well.

In trying to understand why: it seems you are making a break in the set at the first value that is assigned to `FALSE`, then setting all values after that value to `FALSE`. Is there anything you would add to this conceptualization?

Comment: I know realize my previous understanding was incorrect. I understand how this works now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be using `dplyr`. Check previous value with `lag` function. If previous value is `NA` or `TRUE` keep do not change value in current row. Otherwise change it to `FALSE`.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- read.table( text = "svd next_svd      delta Component_Selected
286178.77 54993.91 4.20382638                TRUE
54993.91 25194.36 1.18278651                TRUE
25194.36 19643.22 0.28259842               FALSE
19643.22 15580.04 0.26079366               FALSE
15580.04 14549.86 0.07080343               FALSE
14549.86 11496.45 0.26559570               FALSE", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

df %>%
  mutate(Component_Selected = ifelse(is.na(lag(Component_Selected)) | lag(Component_Selected) ,Component_Selected, FALSE))

        svd next_svd      delta Component_Selected
1 286178.77 54993.91 4.20382638               TRUE
2  54993.91 25194.36 1.18278651               TRUE
3  25194.36 19643.22 0.28259842              FALSE
4  19643.22 15580.04 0.26079366              FALSE
5  15580.04 14549.86 0.07080343              FALSE
6  14549.86 11496.45 0.26559570              FALS
```